# Ubuntu and Windows Dual-boot Automatically Starts Windows (NO ACCESS TO UEFI/BIOS)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I think my laptop is totally broken at this point, here’s what happened step by step.

1. I was trying to do an assignment using Hadoop and while installing Hadoop it required permissions so I kept messing with permissions until I destroyed filesystem permissions but installing hadoop remains a different problem that I won’t talk about yet. After destroying the permissions, I tried to reinstall from Windows (GNU GRUB 2.2 WAS FULLY WORKING)
2. Uninstalled Ubuntu by freeing its partition and I had no USB stick with another install at that time, I wanted to install it through Windows.
3. Restarted my laptop to find myself stuck with GNU GRUB 2.2 Console (but rescue mode maybe) after endless trials to resume to Windows I found the command exit.
4. Installed Ubuntu on a USB stick and inserted it then rebooted. When rebooted it still starts at GNU GRUB 2.2 console so I ran the following commands: a. set root=(path of usb stick) b. set prefix=(path of usb stick)/grub c. insmod normal d. normal
5. Afterwards, Ubuntu starts installing.
6. After installing Ubuntu now automatically boots (no grub) and I have no option to boot Windows.
7. When booting I tried pressing all keys (F2, ESC, Shift, F12, F8 and many more) to access BIOS but it doesn’t work.
8. Tried to install rEFInd through Ubuntu, and restarted to get ‘System compromised. Halting’ then it started Ubuntu automatically in Secure Boot mode I think.
9. Used boot-repair and Gparted as attempts to access the BIOS/UEFI or to fix boot loader. Operations were successful but no change happened while booting.
10. Turned off Secure Boot through boot-repair and rebooted I was greeted by a message: Secure Boot Image failed to verify with *ACESS DENIED* Press any key to continue which boots Windows automatically.
11. Tried to update BIOS through Windows through Lenovo’s website (my model is ideapad z580).
12. Running the BIOS(public updater) as administrator crashes with exit code 255 (WinFlash64.exe has stopped working)

These are mostly the steps I tried to bring my laptop back to life. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated as I have been messing stuff up more and more every day for a week.
The only thing left for me to try is to restart BIOS by removing the CMOS battery for a couple of minutes but I’m not entirely sure it will work.

Comment: You need access to UEFI settings if you're trying to install any OS and particularly a dual-boot as there are some changes that need to be made, namely to the boot order. Not having access is NOT AN OPTION. You need to check your user's manual and/or online resources to know exactly which key to use (or boot to UEFI settings from Windows), not press random keys and expect it to work. You need to familiarize yourself with your specific hardware or not try what you're trying at all, you risk ending up with no bootable OS and then what?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have no access to BIOS AT ALL. Even tried the what they call ‘Novo Button’ which brings up menu that has: Normal Start, BIOS Setup, Boot Menu and System Recovery. 2 and 3 bring up the message Security Boot Access Denied then boot Windows automatically. 1 and 4 boot Windows automatically.

Comment: Try booting into UEFI settings from Windows (google it, too long for a comment). If the problem persists please contact your tech support. Sorry for just stating the obvious.

Comment: I may have not mentioned that accessing UEFI through Windows doesn't work as well, it just asks me to restart then it starts Windows like nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried a full "cold" boot, not the warm reboot? That is shutdown, remove battery, hold power switch to drain any left over power. Then on boot, you may have time to press a key to get into UEFI. There is a UEFI setting called fast boot, which is different than Windows fast start up. Fast boot is usually so quick that you do not have time to press any keys, it is assuming no system changes and boots previous configuration already written to drive for operating system.

Comment: @oldfred I tried the cold boot, it didn't work. I guess I'm destined to use Windows forever.

Comment: Then it is jumper some pins on motherboard, see manual or remove coin battery. That should reset UEFI to defaults. You then have to redo any settings in UEFI that you previously changed. Every UEFI update also resets many settings to defaults. I have to keep a list as I have multiple settings I change.